# Why the Difference in Nomenclature?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

Why is it that in .aspx pages all events are preceded with "`On`" e.g. "`OnClick`", "`OnCommand`" and in the code-behind file they are referred "`Click`", "`Command`"? Just Naming Convention or is there some logical explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names of the events themselves are Click, Change, etc...  The internal methods to fire those events from code are prefixed with "On" as a naming convention. In ASP.NET markup, you use the attribute OnClick but what you're really doing is wiring a method to the "Click" event. Therefore, the method autogenerated for you by VS is ButtonName_Click. This method is internally passed as a delegate to the event itself.

Comment: On Click, do the Click Method. I guess one could called it `Button1_Clicked` method, for more accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, just naming convention. They had to start with something :-) Prior to ASP.NET I think it was also like this in Windows applications and in JavaScript.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/puranindia/165/

http://webdevelopersjournal.com/articles/jsevents1/jsevents1.html

Comment: Just a name convention that follows VB style. Interesting that Delphi/VCL convention is just the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I may have your question wrong, but from what I can tell by what your asking, the EVENT and the PROPERTY cannot have the same name

The event is "Click"... example.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
```

But in the actual control, there is a property called "OnClick" whereby it activates the "Click" event.  Therefor they cannot be named the same thing.